# Rest Assured - Unable to parse JSON Document when doing a POST request with params and headers

Tags: java, json, post, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Currently I am getting the below error when trying to perform a post Request in Rest Assured and looking to get the "tokenId" from the response body:

```
io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document

    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getString(JsonPath.java:352)
    at com.restassured.oauth.AuthenticateSetup.authenticationSetup(AuthenticateSetup.java:39)
    at com.restassured.runner.TestRunner.testNgBeforeSuite(TestRunner.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
    ... 25 more
```

The code I have is as seen below:

```
public class AuthenticateSetup {

    public static Response response;
    public static String responseString;
    public static ReadPropertyFile urlProperties;

    public void authenticationSetup() throws JsonException {

        urlProperties = new ReadPropertyFile("./src/test/resources/Url.properties");
        RestAssured.baseURI = urlProperties.getProperty("devAuthBaseUrl");
        response = given()
                .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("*/*", ContentType.JSON)))
                //.contentType(ContentType.ANY)
                .param("authIndexType", "service")
                .param("authIndexValue", "ldapService")
                .header("host", RestAssured.baseURI)
                .header("X-OpenAM-Username",urlProperties.getProperty("contactId"))
                .header("X-OpenAM-Password",urlProperties.getProperty("contactPwd"))
                .header("Accept-API-Version","resource=2.0,protocol=1.0")
                .when()
                .post(urlProperties.getProperty("devVGWAuthenticateUrl"))
                .then()
//                .assertThat()
//                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();

        System.out.println("The response is " + response);
        String tokenId = response.jsonPath().getString("tokenId");
        System.out.println("The token id is " + tokenId);
    }
}
```

At first I was getting an encoding error so I added the config.  Below is the postman request that works just fine in postman:

[image]

Is there any reason I am unable to parse the JSON?  Also if I turn on the .assertThat().statuscode(200) call I am getting a 400 error for bad request.  Any help would be appreciated as I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: You should log the RA request and find out what is the difference between RA and Postman. Because your request is `bad request` meaning some key-value is wrong, the response is HTML, starting with `<` character --> RA throws JSON Exception while parsing it.

Comment: 1) `Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON` - looks like you get XML in response, not JSON; 2) add whole error stack trace when you get `400 bad request`; 3) Postman add some additional headers, e.g. `Content-Type` header, check it